# Running iPhone application on iPad shows a black bar on top of the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have see a black bar on top of the iPad app , actually app is designed for iPhone and running in iPad, Not able to reproduce in iPhone  and this happens very rare.
[image]
Please Help on how to fix this issue

Comment: If you have designed for iPhone then how could you expect to run it smoothly in iPad? Your client is also crazy enough to expect these things.

Comment: tell your client ***you will get what you want***. *This is an iPhone app and you will have that behavior in iPad. If you want full screen let us make iPad app too*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you create the .xib file for ipad or storyboard? if so the also change your device in the deployment info section from iphone to universal.

Comment: we are targeting only for iPhone , but user is testing in iPad.  And he want to use in both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: if this is the case then you should create the app universal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create universal application for both iPhone or iPad, currently your application target only iPhone Device.

Comment: We are  targeting only for iPhone , but user is testing in iPad.